# Return row count with WHERE Clause and without filtering

Tags: t-sql

I want to display the row count of a select statement with an inner join and a `where` clause and also display the row count of that same table without any of the filtering.

It would be something similar to this. The problem is that these subselects are frowned upon:

```
SELECT count(1) as ValidCount,
(SELECT count(1) from TableAll) as AllCount
from TableAll inner join TableSelected on
TableAll.EmpId = TableSelected.EmpId
where 
TableAll.IsValid = 1
```

Comment: Who is doing the frowning?

Comment: I guess I'm talking about making it part of the SQL instead of just a separate statement. For example, if I want to add other filters to that 2nd line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server you can get a table's row count from the system view *sys.partitions* thus avoiding actually having to scan the table / index.

For example:

```
SELECT count(1) as ValidCount, (
    SELECT rows 
    from sys.partitions 
    where Object_Id = Object_Id('dbo.TableAll') and index_id < 2
  ) as AllCount
from TableAll a 
join TableSelected s on a.EmpId = s.EmpId
where a.IsValid = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the filter into a `count` or `sum`:

```
select Count(*) as AllCount,
  Count( case when TableAll.IsValid = 1 then 1 end ) as ValidCount
  from TableAll inner join
    TableSelected on TableAll.EmpId = TableSelected.EmpId;
```

The default value of a `case` expression is `null`, which `count` will ignore.

If the query requires a table scan then it may not impact performance. If there is an index on `IsValid` then Stu's answer may perform better. Or a single index on `TableAll` containing `IsValid` (descending) and `EmpId`.

Comment: Just to point out the `count(*)` will count only rows that join, not all rows in the left table which is what I assume the OP is after.

Comment: @Stu I had realized that and had considered the OP's "the row count of that same table without any of the filtering" to be unclear. Does it refer to both the `join` and `where` as filters or is it referring to the result of the `join` as the "table" and the `where` as the filter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case in a sum aggregate to get the selected employees and then count the allTable like this:

```
SELECT 
     SUM(CASE WHEN IsValid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS [ValidCount]
     ,COUNT(*)
FROM TableAll
```